# Design methodology - Single-Phase vs Three-Phase Inverter

Tags: power-electronics, inverter

I simulated a small DC Microgrid in Matlab/Simulink. In order to connect the DC bus of the microgrid to the AC grid, I used a three-phase - two-level inverter.

I have done some research and I found out that for an application like mine (a small power application) it's better to use one phase inverter.

So, in Simulink its pretty easy to convert a three-phase inverter to one phase but I would like to ask if the parameters (modulation index, the switching frequency, the dc link capacitor size e.t.c. ) that I used in the three-phase inverter, can be used for the one phase inverter. In other words, if I use the same parameters for the one phase inverter, my system will work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current ripple will be higher by about 50% in the single-phase inverter if you go with the same switching frequency (which means the same semiconductor losses). So you might increase the inductance and/or increase the switching frequency.

In single-phase the power is not constant any more, but pulsates with two times the fundamental frequency. Therefore, you will see a low-frequency voltage ripple on the DC link, and you might need to increase the DC link capacitor (significantly).

To take into account the voltage ripple on the DC link in the single-phase system, you will probably have to change the voltage-control loop dynamics and make the voltage controller slower to avoid instability.